# JPA mapping a composite key with null values

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I am using legacy database to read static data where key column does not exist. Hence In JPA entity its a composite column.

```
class Person
{

 private PersonId id;

 @EmbeddedId
 @AttributeOverrides({
 @AttributeOverride(name = "firstName", 
          column = @Column(name = "first_Name", precision = 4, scale = 0)),@AttributeOverride(name = "dob", 
          column = @Column(name = "dobr", precision = 4, scale = 0))
})
 public PersonId getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}

class PersonId {
String firstName;
String dob;

// getter & setter
}
```

So, when I am send JPAQL, I am getting list with null. I know hibernate set null if either of composite key attribute value is null. But as I can not have an option to ensure all composite key can be not null, hence looking for suggestions

Comment: Where is Entity class ?

Comment: Person is the entity class.

Comment: It is not having @Entity annotation. Are you mixing xml config with annotation config ?

Comment: Are the records in the table all unique ? If yes, you can create a new column with an id field having unique numeric values.

Comment: It is. Missed it while posting question.

Comment: its a composite key and few columns of this key can accept null values. I do not have an option to add a new column (strategic solution). I am looking for a tactical one  for this issue. Basically, we do not have option to alter the table in database.

Comment: In that case, its Not possible with hibernate. Hibernate requires a primary key or composite keys to work with.